# Android App User to Update App if current version > market version without cancel button

Tags: android

[image: List item]

Is it possible to remove cross button?

Comment: Why do you want to remove cancel button? Let the user decide what to do with this. And it is NOT POSSIBLE

Comment: If you remove the X, what's stopping the back or home buttons from stopping the update?

Comment: not possible only you can change constant to show user update or not  https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/play/core/install/model/UpdateAvailability.html#UNKNOWN